# how to prevent flash from scaling / resizing my content in a web browser?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, resize, scale

I have finished my flash game, but when I used web Browser such as Chrome or FireFox to run it, it enlarged my game to full size of the browser. Is there anyway( in AS3 script) that I could prevent this from happening as well as hide the symbols that their sizes are bigger than  my default size defined at the document property panel?

Comment: Brian, what symbols do you mean with "hide the symbolds that their sizes are bigger". Who is their?

Comment: its the symbol size, because if its size is bigger than the stage, when we open flash by webBrowser, we can see the remainder of the symbols out of the stage. Hope you could understand that...

Comment: You want to hide all objects that are bigger than the stage?

Comment: only the bigger part, the part that goes outside off the stage; the part that in the stage still visible. is it possible?

Comment: Usually you put your SWF into an appropriate HTML element e.g. `<object>`. That will clip the movie to the size specified in width and height properties of that element. You run your movie directly? Then you should apply a mask.

Comment: yup! maybe this is how thing works! sorry to bother you for so long. Thank a lot ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prevent your application to be resized by setting `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;` in your main application constructor. There are as well other scaleMode values available. See the docs.

Comment: Thank you :D it works. How about the latter question? "hide the symbols that their sizes are bigger than my default size defined at the document property panel" Could you teach me too ^^"

Comment: I am not using Flash, and I do not know these symbols. I hope there is someone else who may help you.